# How to recover the content of the show log module of Omnet++/Tkenv?

Tags: omnet++, veins

I want to recover the content of the show log module of Omnet++/Tkenv (see picture attached here) into a file in order to analyze the traffic happened between nodes and RSU at each time after the end of the simulation.
How can I do this please?

[image]

Comment: have you tried using the clipboard?

Comment: Hi Sir, no I have not used it. How can I use it please? I need, before starting the simulation, runnig something that allows me to recover the content of the show module of Omnet++/ Tkenv after the end of the simulation.

Answer (score 0):

For a one-off simulation running in Tkenv, you can use the clipboard: Right click the module log window, choose `select all`. Right click the log window, choose `copy` to copy the text to the clipboard. Open a text editor of your choosing, right click and select `paste` to insert the text from the clipboard.

For batch simulations running in Cmdenv, you can set two parameters in the `omnetpp.ini` file: `cmdenv-express-mode = false` and `cmdenv-output-file = log.txt` -- this will store the log output in a file.

If you are doing this for result collection, though, better use OMNeT++'s signal, scalar, and vector features.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Sir. Before running the simulation, I have copied the content of the log module into a file named logtxt Then I set the omnetpp.ini and I execute the simulation. In fact the log.txt was not changed. Knowing that I put it /Veins-4a2/log.txt. Why it did not work? I tried also to put the path of the file like this but in vain:  cmdenv-output-file = C:/Users/user/src/veins-4a2/log.txt